Bundle Adjustment with IMU factor
When applying bundle adjustment to a graph with IMU factors during the optimization process, there are two residual terms which involve the state at a particular time.
The current state and the predicted state from the IMU using the current state.
I'm wondering when BA adjustment is run, if both residuals are taken into account for a given state or if only the residual holding the unpropagated state is considered?
Ex, R_imu_{t+1}(IMU(X_t),X_{t+1}) while R_imu_{t}(IMU(X_t),X_{t-1})
When taking derivatives, is it taken with respect to both terms or only the first?
